# How to resize an image relative to another image?

Tags: html, css, image, response

I have two images on a page. The one image uses a negative top margin to overlap the other image. Both images are different sizes. The issue I'm having is when you resize the page, the one image with a larger width scales down but the other smaller image remains the same size.

I need the two images to maintain the same size relative to each other as the window is resized. I'm attaching a screenshot of the page.

Thanks for any help!

Html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <img class="section__diagram" src="/wp-content/uploads/product-architecture-cloud-screens.png" />
      <img class="section__diagram" style="margin-top:-92px;" src="/wp-content/uploads/product-architecture-cloud.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Desktop Size Proper Ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtrUS.png)
[Smaller Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5tPb.png)

Comment: really not possible to just render one image from the 2 images? I mean since you want to keep them proportional... or the code structure does not allow that?

Comment: Where's your code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @lopezi unfortunately no.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I added the html

Comment: Have you tried using view port units(`vh`, `vw`)?, so the that both images scale relative to the view port size and will maintain the same scaling.

Comment: @Programninja "The issue I'm having is when you resize the page, the one image with a larger width scales down but the other smaller image remains the same size." That's a CSS issue and you didn't include CSS. And your image links don't work since they're local. Host them somewhere and read this page please and create a **complete, verifiable** example of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Callum No I didn't think of that. It works close enough, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View port units(`vh`, `vw`) should work for what you need. Because the scaling is relative to the view port both images will maintain the same scaling they always had.